# Visual Studio 2012: Error while trying to run project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I get the following error while trying to run a project

```
 "Unable to start program C:\Users\v-nikenv\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PassbyValue\Debug\PassbyValue.exe. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

This happens with any project i have got. It worked perfectly fine about 3 days back, and i don't remember installing/deleting anything form the computer.

The path until "C:\Users\v-nikenv\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PassbyValue\Debug" is existent. But there is no PassbyValue.exe file there.

By the way, i also tried steps here:

```
 Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program. Cannot find the file specified
```

i haven't tried uninstall/re-install though. Any suggestions, except that!?

Thnx and regards :)

Comment: Have you tried rebuild the project again?

Comment: Rebuilt and cleaned it too. Same thing.

Comment: Have you changed the Set as Startup Project? I've done it a time or two and seen the issues you are describing.

Comment: first look at the path in the message if the exe is actually here or not; if there try to run it manually

Comment: "Rebuilt and cleaned it too" - rebuilt and cleaned? Or cleaned and rebuilt? Rebuilt successfully? No errors?

Comment: Clearly you can't run a program when it doesn't exist.  You'll need to find the black hole in which the EXE disappears when you build your project.  Do pay attention to the Error List window first, you can't run the program when it failed to build.  Disable your virus scanner next.  SysInternals' ProcMon is a good black-hole detector.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project, copy the code from source file of this project to a new source file in the newly created project, then compile and execute it, hope it works fine then...
The **".exe"** file in this project is causing some problem or files are missing.. A new project can be helpful for these repairs.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem when debugging an x64 application. Tried a few things, and this seems to work for me:

At the project properties page, click Debug, uncheck "Enable native debugging" and "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".